# Lag in data getting into elasticsearch from kafka

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, elasticsearch-5

I have logs coming into 1 topic of Kafka, I am parsing them and putting them into 2 separate Kafka topic(having 10 partitions each), thereafter I am putting them into elasticsearch via kafka-elastic sink using 10 tasks.
But I am facing serious lag of about 10 minutes lag for 30 minutes of continuous logs which in-turn increases for more logs.
Please suggest to narrow the gap.

Ps. I checked my parser works fine and puts the data into the 2 topics in no time.
Also I am using latest elasticsearch 6 and kafka.